# How do I add Special:PrefixIndex/FULLPAGENAME to the toolbox in my local MediaWIki installation?

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I would like a tool in the sidebar's "Tools" section that takes readers to `Special:PrefixIndex/FULLPAGENAME` where `FULLPAGENAME` is replaced with the current page's full name. For example, say I was on the page `Module:Citation/CS1` then I would like a tool in the sidebar called `Subpages` that takes me to `Special:PrefixIndex/Module:Citation/CS1`. I have seen ([the mediawiki sidebar manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar#Add_or_remove_toolbox_sections_.28JavaScript.29)) and I added:

```
function CustomizeModificationsOfSidebar() {
    // Adds PrefixIndex
    var page = mw.config.get( 'wgPageName' );
    ModifySidebar( 'add', 'toolbox', 'Subpages', "http://127.0.0.1/mediawiki/index.php/Special:PrefixIndex/"'page' );
}

jQuery( CustomizeModificationsOfSidebar );
```

to the page `MediaWiki:Common.js`. This gave the JavaScript error: `Error: Expected ')' and instead saw 'page'.` that prevented me from saving the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is missing a comma, it should be

```
    ModifySidebar( 'add', 'toolbox', 'Subpages', 'http://127.0.0.1/mediawiki/index.php/Special:PrefixIndex/', 'page' );
```

Of course, you will have to add the actual `ModifySidebar` function to.

**Alternative approach:**
Though not recommended in the manual, you *can* actually use magic words, such as `{{FULLPAGENAME}}` in `MediaWiki:Sidebar`, so adding something like this should work:

```
*Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}|subpages
```

You might run in to caching troubles, though. Make sure [`$wgEnableSidebarCache`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableSidebarCache) is off in `LocalSettings.php` (it is by default)

Edit: The comment from Tgr below is also very relevant: This will have performance implications

Comment: That will force the sidebar to be reparsed on every pageview which is probably a bad idea for any site which gets nontrivial traffic.