# How do I remove items from the toolbox in MediaWiki?

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I have a Local MediaWiki 1.25.1 installation on my 32 bit Ubuntu 15.04 PC and while I have a script (written in JavaScript) for adding items to the toolbox in my `MediaWiki:Common.js` page, which I have from asking people on the Wikia support forums about how to add items to the toolbox when my Wiki was still hosted by Wikia, I do not have one that removes items from the toolbox. As I am no longer on Wikia I have to find elsewhere to this question, hence why I am here at SO. Currently this is my `MediaWiki:Common.js` page:

```
$(function() {
    mw.util.addPortletLink('p-tb', mw.util.wikiGetlink('Special:CategoryTree'), 'CategoryTree', false, 'Show category tree page');
    mw.util.addPortletLink('p-tb', mw.util.wikiGetlink('Special:Export/'+mw.config.get('wgPageName')), 'Export current page', false, 'Export current page as XML');
    mw.util.addPortletLink('p-tb', mw.util.wikiGetlink('Special:Export'), 'Export pages', false, 'Export pages as XML');
    mw.util.addPortletLink('p-tb', mw.util.wikiGetlink('Special:Import'), 'Import pages', false, 'Import pages as XML');
    mw.util.addPortletLink('p-tb', mw.util.wikiGetlink('Special:PrefixIndex/'+mw.config.get('wgPageName')), 'List subpages', false, 'Get a list of subpages of this page');
});
```

which adds items called `CategoryTree`, `Export current page`, `Export pages`, *etc.* to the Toolbox.

Now I was hoping that someone could help me with removing items from the toolbox. For those that do not fully know what I'm talking about, in the screenshot shown below:

[image]

the toolbox is what appears under the heading "Tools" in the left-hand side of the page. By the way, I have attempted using a modified version of [leo's answer to a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703798/1876983) namely:

```
ModifySidebar( 'remove', 'toolbox', 'Upload file', 'http://localhost/linux/index.php/Special:Upload' );
```

needless to say, or otherwise I wouldn't be here, it failed. One of the links I'd like to remove is "Page information" which is dependent on the `wgPageName` variable too (namely it is `http://localhost/linux/index.php?title=wgPageName&action=info`), just like the links I add with the script currently in my `MediaWiki:Common.js` page, hence any answer you give me I would like to be able to use (with simple modification) for this purpose. Please keep in mind I am a novice JavaScript user, so answers NOT in JavaScript/programming jargon would certainly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have something to do with running it on localhost, as it works fine for me.

You don't actually have to supply both the "name" paramter and the "link" parameter to remove an item, it's an either/or - so you should try the same without the link, namely:

`ModifySidebar( 'remove', 'toolbox', 'Upload file' );`

This should also solve your problem with "Page information" - simply don't supply the link for removal.